# php -v command gives "dyld: Library not loaded" error

Tags: php, macos-mojave

php not working in my pc.
apache server is working.

when check php version on terminal it gives below error.

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib/libicui18n.63.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/php
  Reason: image not found
Abort trap: 6
```

Answer (score -1):

- Completely uninstall the homebrew/php install
  $ brew uninstall --force php@7.1
- Un-tap homebrew-php since we will not be needing it any longer
  $ brew untap homebrew/php
- Next, I ran some brew commands to cleanup dead symlinks and older installs. This is a Brew wide operations, so completely optional if you don’t want to do this part.
  $ brew prune && brew cleanup
- Update Homebrew and formulae
  $ brew update
- Install the homebredw-core version of PHP 7.1
  $ brew install php71

reference (https://mark.shropshires.net/blog/how-reinstall-homebrew-php-after-move-homebrewphp-homebrewcore)

now the result for the command `php -version`

```
PHP 7.1.19 (cli) (built: Aug 17 2018 20:10:18) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
```